# Windows Phone remove specific BackStack entry

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, navigationservice

I am trying to remove the specific `BackStack` entry from `NavigationService.BackStack`.

I found there is one method to remove back entry i.e. `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();`, but it remove all back entries from `stack`. So, my question is **How to remove specific back entry?**

How can I remove the query string from `NavigationService.CurrentSource`? I want retrieve only `Uri` without `Query String`.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can't do that and you shouldn't because it would mess with people's expectation of what happens when you click the Back button.

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove specific back stack entity, because your current stack(current page) can interact with its adjacent stack only, So can remove only its previous stack entity.
You need to remove stack at time of NavigateTo() next page.

Answer (score -1):

I can do that with this code. 
Insert this into a page.Loaded event:

```
int backstackcounter = this.NavigationService.BackStack.Count();

            for (int i = 0; i < backstackcounter; i++)
            {
               var previousPage = this.NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault();

                if (previousPage != null && !previousPage.Source.ToString().StartsWith("/LoginPage.xaml"))
                {
                    this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                }
            }
```

The "LoginPage.xaml" is a page that i want to stay in the backstack.

Comment: You cant traverse the BackStack this way. this.NavigationService.BackStack.FirstOrDefault() will always give you the first element. plus RemoveBackEntry() will always remove the most recent element. SO if you most recent element is no the login page, this code will never work.